# Dificuldade em atribuir valorer em plsql

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Em um exercício da faculdade foi pedido o seguinte:

> Em uma eleição presidencial existem tres candidatos. Os votos são
>   informados por código. Os dados utilizados para a escrutinagem
>   obedecem a seguinte codificação:  1, 2, 3 = votos para os respectivos
>   candidatos;  4 = voto nulo;  5 = voto em branco. Escreva um programa
>   em PlSql que calcule e escreva:  O total de votos para cada candidato;
>   O total de votos nulos; O total de votos em branco. Como finalizador
>   do conjunto de votos, tem-se o valor 0 (zero).

Minha resposta foi a seguinte

```
declare
valorVoto number type:= &voto;
votosDeputado1 number:= 0;
votosDeputado2 number:= 0;
votosDeputado3 number:= 0;
votosNulos number;
votosBrancos number;

begin
if valorVoto = 1 then 
  votosDeputado2:=votosDeputado2 + 1;
end if;

if valorVoto = 2 then 
  votosDeputado2:=votosDeputado2 + 1;
end if;

if valorVoto = 3 then 
  votosDeputado3:=votosDeputado3 + 1;
end if;

if valorVoto = 4  then
  votosNulos := votosNulos+1;
end if;

if valorVoto = 5  then
  votosBrancos := votosbrancos+1;
end if;


  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('O primeiro candidato teve ' || votosDeputado1);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('O segundo candidato teve ' || votosDeputado2);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('O terceiro candidato teve ' || votosDeputado3);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('O total de votos nulos foi ' || votosNulos);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('O total de votos em branco foi ' || votosBrancos);

end;
```

porem a única saída que eu tenho é a seguinte

> ORA-06550: linha 2, coluna 18: PLS-00103: Encontrado o símbolo "TYPE"
>   quando um dos seguintes símbolos era esperado:
>
> := . ( @ % ; not nulo faixa default caractere O símbolo "." foi
>   substituído por "TYPE" para continuar.
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Qual quer ajuda é bem vinda : )

Comment: O que pretendeu com a linha      valorVoto number type:= &voto;     ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucas, baste retirar o `type`, ficando da forma abaixo:

```
declare
valorVoto number := &voto;
votosDeputado1 number:= 0;
votosDeputado2 number:= 0;
...
```